# ObjectBox - query on nested relationship

Tags: java, relationship, objectbox

I have the following `Entity` classes

```
@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class MultiplayerGameEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private int durationInHours;
    private ToMany<MultiplayerPlayerEntity> players;

    public MultiplayerGameEntity() {
    }

    public int getDurationInHours() {
        return durationInHours;
    }

    public void setDurationInHours(int durationInHours) {
        this.durationInHours = durationInHours;
    }

    public ToMany<MultiplayerPlayerEntity> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(ToMany<MultiplayerPlayerEntity> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

and

```
@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class MultiplayerPlayerEntity extends BaseEntity {

    public ToOne<UserEntity> userEntity;
    public ToMany<MultiplayerRoundEntity> rounds;

    public MultiplayerPlayerEntity() {
    }
}
```

and finally

```
@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String uniqueId;
    private String displayName;
    private ToMany<UserEntity> friends;

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    public UserEntity(String uniqueId, String displayName) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public ToMany<UserEntity> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(ToMany<UserEntity> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}
```

I am trying to do a search and bring back all `MultiplayerGameEntity` that contain a given `UserEntity`

in SQL terms (as this is how my brain works) I'd be `JOIN`ing `MultiplayerGameEntity` to `MultiplayerPlayerEntity` and then `MultiplayerPlayerEntity` to `UserEntity`

I've tried to do this using `link()` but I can't seem to work out how to link the second relationship.

code so far...

```
            queryBuilder.link(MultiplayerGameEntity_.players);
            queryBuilder.link(MultiplayerPlayerEntity_.userEntity).equal(UserEntity_.uniqueId, uniqueId);
            return queryBuilder.build().find();
        }
```

but this doesn't work stating

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Relation not part of Entity MultiplayerPlayerEntity (17)`

Is it even possible to do what I'm doing, or do I need to hack this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it working, by making the links chain together so the second link is to the result of the previous link (which is actually a diff QueryBuilder)

```
QueryBuilder<MultiplayerGameEntity> queryBuilder = box.query();
queryBuilder.link(MultiplayerGameEntity_.players).link(MultiplayerPlayerEntity_.userEntity).equal(UserEntity_.uniqueId, uniqueId);
```

Comment: Yeap, that should be it! For completion an explanation: the original code did not work as the `userEntity` relation is not accessible directly from the `MultiplayerGameEntity_` entity info. Using `QueryBuilder.link(relationInfo)` returns a `QueryBuilder` that can access relations of the target entity info `relationInfo` points to.